# EntityFrameworkCore - Unable to Create Instance of Abstract Class or Interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am trying to implement (port from an older MVC 5 project) group based  permissions on .NET core and am getting the error

> Unable to Create Instance of Abstract Class or Interface `UserStore`.

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
  new UserStore<ApplicationUser, 
      ApplicationRole, 
      DbContext, 
      string, 
      ApplicationUserClaim, 
      ApplicationUserRole, 
      ApplicationUserLogin, 
      IdentityUserToken<string>>
  (context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
);
```

I didn't used get this error on the original MVC 5 project but I am unable to resolve this on .Net Core. Please help.

Here's the config.cs file.

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MFMIS.Models
{
    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.

    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger)
            : base(store,optionsAccessor,passwordHasher,userValidators,passwordValidators,keyNormalizer,errors,services,logger)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
            IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, DbContext, string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, IdentityUserToken<string>>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };
            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };
            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "SecurityCode",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the RoleManager used in the application. RoleManager is defined in the ASP.NET Identity core assembly
    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole> roleStore)
            : base(roleStore)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationRoleManager(new ApplicationRoleStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        }
    }





    // This is useful if you do not want to tear down the database each time you run the application.
    // public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
    // This example shows you how to create a new database if the Model changes
    public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
            base.Seed(context);
        }

        //Create User=Admin@Admin.com with password=Admin@123456 in the Admin role        
        public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            const string name = "admin@example.com";
            const string password = "Admin@123456";
            const string roleName = "Admin";

            //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
            var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
            if (role == null)
            {
                role = new ApplicationRole(roleName);
                var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
            }

            var user = userManager.FindByName(name);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name, EmailConfirmed = true };
                var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
                result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);

            }

            var groupManager = new ApplicationGroupManager();
            var newGroup = new ApplicationGroup("SuperAdmins", "Full Access to All");

            groupManager.CreateGroup(newGroup);
            groupManager.SetUserGroups(user.Id, new string[] { newGroup.Id });
            groupManager.SetGroupRoles(newGroup.Id, new string[] { role.Name });
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) :
            base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        { }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

In case you want to try out the project locally to check for dependencies,[here's the link.](https://github.com/shubhamranjan/Group-Based-Permissions-.NET-Core)

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation [here](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore-TUser-TRole-TContext-TKey-TUserClaim-TUserRole-TUserLogin-TUserToken/index.html) - the class you're trying to instantiate is abstract. Try using [this one](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore-TUser/index.html) like so:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

EDIT: I can see another potential problem in this code. The constructor of `ApplicationUserManager` class requires 9 parameters and here it's invoked with one. You may need to supply the rest of them as well.

Comment: I dont need those many parameters but the base class UserManager needs all those.Have been trying to figure this for a lot of time.All I want is 

`        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }` . 

Can you help me out ?

Comment: Not sure what you're after, but you can try to look for default implementations like [PasswordHasher](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Identity/PasswordHasher-TUser/index.html?highlight=passwordhasher) and [UserValidator](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Identity/UserValidator-TUser/index.html?highlight=uservalidator)
You can try to search for the other ones in the documentation. Btw - you're saying that it's a port from older project. Was `ApplicationUserManager` part of this older project as well?

Comment: Yes, Here it is https://github.com/TypecastException/AspNetIdentity2GroupPermissions/tree/master/AspNetIdentity2GroupPermissions

Comment: In Earlier Versions , UserStore used to be a non - abstract class.

I am trying to implement group based permissions ,Users assigned to groups where groups are a collection of roles.

Comment: nd Here's my current repo (.NET core) : https://github.com/shubhamranjan/Group-Based-Permissions-.NET-Core